# What is Detach Entity mean?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

What is the meaning of detached entity. In my course following in Spring Framework Guru. We made a DTO, Does it mean when you fetched data from db then convert it in DTO is it called Detached Entity?

Answer (score 0):

A detached entity is an entity which state must not be reflected by the JPA provider.

In other words, if you change its state (i.e. through setters methods) these changes will not be saved to the underlying database, as the JPA provider doesn't have to "observe" such entities.

If entity E1 is a managed entity you can make it detached invoking (very reasonable named) method EntityManager#detach(E1). You can also use EntityManager#clear() which will clear whole PersistenceContext and effectively making all managed entities detached.

Comment: He just convert it to command POJO so is it consider as detached entity. Because he made a copy of fetched object?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote a [blog article on this general subject](https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/the-bag/) that helps to answer this question, and I post it here as a separate answer only because it comes at the subject from a slightly different perspective.